# Android webview script tag not loading source file

Tags: java, android, html, webview

I'm trying to load a javascript file from a script tag in Webview, but it won't load it!

here's the source for the HTML Script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/game/tetris.js"></script>
```

And the java file:

```
WebView webview;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/game/tetris.html");
}
```

I've tried with and without the "file:///android_asset/game/" and it still won't load!

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what doesn't load - only the JS or also the HTML? Simply put some markup into the HTML and see if it is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I do the same in my applications with relative paths, and it works fine for me.

In this case I'd simply use `src="tetris.js"` in the HTML